# Reliably disassamble bytecode to opcodes across various evm versions

Tags: solidity, evm, compiler, opcode

Is there a reliable way of disassembling bytecode into opcodes across different EVM versions, to make it agnostic to the EVM version used during compilation?

As the second best option - is there a disassembler, that allows you to specify the EVM version to use?
I did plenty of research on line but haven't found anything like this.
I'm currently using evmdasm:
https://github.com/ethereum/evmdasm

But it was not updated for a long time, so, as an example of the problem - with the release of Shanghai, and introduction of `PUSH0`, for contracts, compiled with Shanghai EVM version I have opcode `UNKNOWN_0x5f`(basically unrecognized opcode 0x5f), while same operation in contract compiled using Paris version, will look like `PUSH1 0x00`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested. I found an existing package, that allows you to select evm version to use during disassembling:
https://github.com/crytic/pyevmasm